# EclipseLink2.5 Heirachical Select JPA

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have a query based on the samples provided at
http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2013/06/eclipselink-supports-hql-and-several.html
    Hierarchical Selects section.

I have a single table with hierarchical data and can have 'nth' levels, So on further testing i realized it does a bottom -> top traverse i.e

```
CONNECT BY PRIOR PARENT_ID = ID
```

Is there anyway i can flip it to do a Top -> Bottom traverse i.e

```
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = PARENT_ID
```

without resulting to doing create native query, i'm using an oracle database btw.